# Как очищать то, что появляется в консоли RUN после запуска кода в Pycharm?

Tags: python, консоль, pycharm

Мне нужно добавить в код элемент, который будет удалять всё содержимое консоли, кроме последнего выведенного в ней элемента.

Пример.

```
Задание А1
Укажите число, в котором 8 сотен и 1 единица.
Варианты ответа:
1. 180
2. 108
3. 810
4. 801
Введите номер правильного варианта: 2 #введено пользователем
Неверно. Попробуйте еще раз.
```

В данном примере через некоторый период времени (2-3 секунды) должно быть удалено всё, кроме строки `неверно. попробуйте ещё раз.`, после чего в консоли появится следующий вывод, запланированный по программе.

Где-то прочитал, что тут идёт зависимость от версии ПО и Pycharm, поэтому напишу, на всякий случай, что ПО у меня Windows 10.

Удаляться всё должно в консоли Pycharm, так как в неё всё и выводится.

UPD: Под консолью я имею ввиду вкладку RUN, которая появляется после запуска программы в PyCharm. Очищаться эта вкладка должна автоматически, через код. Т.е. я написал код, в котором после определённого кол-ва информации должна очищаться вкладка RUN. Как сделать так, чтобы RUN очищалась автоматически через код и после очистки продолжила идти информация, которая должна была идти и без очистки?

Comment: Не легче перед тем как выдать верный/неверный ответ, очищать консоль и затем вывести?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27241268/clear-pycharm-run-window

Answer (score 1):

```
import os
os.system('CLS')
```

В Vs коде очищает А на счет Pycharm - не знаю.

Comment: а в блокноте как? файловую систему удаляет?